# Magento plugin for adding product from backend?

Tags: php, magento, plugins, module

Is there any plugin using which we can add product details at one page only..Instead of selecting the different tabs from the admin dashboard while adding products ??

Suggest any plugin if its there or whether can we make a custom one ?

Answer (score 0):

i had an similar problem, but had no plugin installed.
i resovled this, by reordering the attribut sets and the attributes there. 
so the "general" contains all necessary attributes, needed to display the product in the shop....

Answer (score 0):

simply reorder attribute sets from

`Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes set -> select your attribute set -> Drag and drop attributes -> Save`

this will help you